# Jmeter: Json Extractor: Response from first request to be used in next Request

Tags: jmeter

I have a Http request for which i am getting data from CSV data file and i am getting a response body as {"abc":"123456123"}. I have added JSON extractor as child to this Http request. I am given variable name as abc and tried json path as both $..abc or $.abc and now i have added new Http request(2) in which i want to pass variable name from json extractor in request body(2). I have used same variable name in the http request body(2) but the variable name is not passing in the new request.

I gave all the options in json path in json extractor, i am expecting that for each response {"abc":"123456123"}(this value will change for each request) json extractor should get the response value and pass in the next request body.

When i am running the script, the value is not passed in request2.

Response of request 1 :- for single thread
{"abc":"123456123"}

Json Extractor:-
name of variable : abc
JSON path:- $.abc

Request 2:-

```
{
  "a":{
    "b":[
      {
        "mRID":"${abc}",
        "abc":[
          {
            "a":[
              {
                "n":[
                  {
                    "na":[
                      {
                        "a":"",
                        "a":"AF",
                        "value":"add"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "cr":[
                  {
                    "name":"0071",
                    "nameType":"r#"
                  },
                  {
                    "name":89923,
                    "nameType":"NR#"
                  }
                ],
                "CS":[
                  {
                    "dateTime":"${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss)}",
                    "type":"CS",
                    "value":"x"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue using [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-dummy-sampler) and the [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) configuration you described.

[image]

Try adding [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) after the `uuu` request and see if there is `abc` variable generated and what value does it have.

Also check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for responding, variable value is generated correctly, and thank you pointing to look into jmeter.log, the problem was with the time function, number of parameter passed were wrong.